# Read specific column in perl

Tags: perl

I'm new in perl. I have below text file and from there I want only one `Time` column and next columns are values. How can I create a text file with my desire output in perl.

```
Time  Value    Time    Value    Time    Value
1   0.353366497 1   0.822193251 1   0.780866396
2   0.168834182 2   0.865650713 2   0.42429447
3   0.323540698 3   0.865984245 3   0.856875894
4   0.721728497 4   0.634773162 4   0.563059042
5   0.545131335 5   0.029808531 5   0.645993399
6   0.143720835 6   0.949973296 6   0.14425803
7   0.414601876 7   0.53421424  7   0.826148814
8   0.194818367 8   0.942334356 8   0.837107013
9   0.291448263 9   0.242588271 9   0.939609775
10  0.500159997 10  0.428897293 10  0.41946448
```

I've tried below code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::File;
my $result;
my @files = (q[1.txt],q[2.txt],q[3.txt]);
my @fhs = ();
foreach my $file (@files) { 
    my $fh = new IO::File $file, O_RDONLY;
    push @fhs, $fh if defined $fh;
} 

while(1) { 
    my @lines = map { $_->getline } @fhs;
    last if grep { not defined $_ } @lines[0..(@fhs-1)];
    my @result=join(qq[\t], map { s/[\r?\n]+/ /g; $_ } @lines ) . qq[\r\n];
    open (MYFILE, '>>Result.txt');
    print (MYFILE "@result");
    close (MYFILE);
}
```

Comment: I dont see any code. Its best to update your question. Normally you should provide both input data. Expected output. And at least an attempt at the code to the problen

Comment: I can accumulate three text file together in one. Now i have 6 column text file and from there i want to show just first four column. How can i do it?

Comment: Again its hard to say without seeing your code and knowing the code you have. Hoever you may want to look at split()

Comment: I've tried below code:                                                                           `use strict; use warnings; use IO::File;
my$result;
my @files = (q[1.txt],q[2.txt],q[3.txt]);
my @fhs = ();
foreach my $file (@files)
{
 my $fh = new IO::File $file, O_RDONLY;
 push @fhs, $fh if defined $fh;
}
while(1)
{
 my @lines = map { $_->getline } @fhs;
 last if grep { not defined $_ } @lines[0..(@fhs-1)];
 my@result=join(qq[\t], map { s/[\r?\n]+/ /g; $_ } @lines) . qq[\r\n];
 open (MYFILE, '>>Result.txt');
 print (MYFILE "@result");
 close (MYFILE);
 }`

Comment: @James: `(@fhs-1)` <=> `$#fhs`

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open (my $f, '<', 'your-file.dat') or die;

while (my $line = <$f>) {
  my @elems = split ' ', $line;
  print join "\t", @elems[0,1,3,5];
  print "\n";
}
```

Comment: If you want to format it into neat columns so the headers align with the data below, replace the 2 `print` lines in the while loop with `printf("%4s  %-15s %-15s %-15s\n", @elems[0,1,3,5]);`

Answer (score 1):

This is a one-liner; no need to write a script:

```
$ perl -lanE '$,="\t"; say @F[0,1,3,5]' 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

If you like, you can shorten it to:

```
$ perl -lanE '$,="\t"; say @F[0,1,3,5]' [123].txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're just concatenating the lines of the files together. If that doesn't give you the output you like, you need to chop some columns out.

Since your output looks like you have tab delimited files as input, I split the lines coming in by tabs. And since you only wanted the second column, I only take the column at the first offset from the split.

```
my $line_num = 0;
while(1) {
    my @lines = map { $_->getline } @fhs;
    last if grep { not defined $_ } @lines[0..$#fhs];
    $line_num++;
    my @rows     = map { [ split /\t/ ] } @lines;
    my $time_val = $rows[0][0];
    die "Time values are not all equal on line #$line_num!" 
        if grep { $time_val != $_->[0] } @rows
        ;
    my $result = join( q[\t], $time_val, map { $_->[1] } @rows );
    open (MYFILE, '>>Result.txt');
    print (MYFILE "$result\n");
    close (MYFILE);
}
```

Of course, there is no reason to do custom coding to split delimited columns:

```
use Text::CSV; 
...
my $csv  = Text::CSV->new( { sep_char => "\t" } );

while(1) { 
    my @rows = map { $csv->getline( $_ ) } @fhs;
    last if grep { not defined $_ } @rows[0..$#fhs];
    my ( $time_val, @time_vals ) = map { $_->[0] } @rows;
    my @values = map { $_->[1] } @rows;
    die "Time values are not all equal on line #$line_num!" 
        if grep { $time_val != $_ } @time_vals
        ;
    my $result = join( q[\t], $time_val, @values );
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    use strict;    
use warnings;    
open(FH,"<","a.txt");    
print "=========== A File content =========== \n";    
my $a = `cat a.txt`; 
print "$a\n";  

my @temp = <>;  

    my (@arr, @entries, @final);  
    foreach ( @temp ) {  
         @arr = split ( " ", $_ );  
         push @entries, @arr;  
}  
close FH;

my @entries1 = @entries;  

for(my $i = 7; $i<=$#entries; $i=$i+2) {  

        push @final, $entries[$i];
}

my $size = scalar @final;

open FH1, ">", "b.txt";  
print FH1 "Time \t Value\n";  
for(my $i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {  

        my $j = $i+1;  
        print FH1 "$j \t $final[$i]\n";  
}

close FH1;    

print "============ B file content ===============\n";    
my $b = `cat b.txt`;    
print "$b";


O/P:    
=========== A File content ===========  
Time  Value    Time    Value    Time    Value    
1   0.353366497 1   0.822193251 1   0.780866396   
2   0.168834182 2   0.865650713 2   0.42429447  
3   0.323540698 3   0.865984245 3   0.856875894  
4   0.721728497 4   0.634773162 4   0.563059042  
5   0.545131335 5   0.029808531 5   0.645993399  
6   0.143720835 6   0.949973296 6   0.14425803  
7   0.414601876 7   0.53421424  7   0.826148814  
8   0.194818367 8   0.942334356 8   0.837107013  
9   0.291448263 9   0.242588271 9   0.939609775  
10  0.500159997 10  0.428897293 10  0.41946448  

============ B file content ===============  
Time     Value  
1        0.353366497  
2        0.822193251  
3        0.780866396  
4        0.168834182  
5        0.865650713  
6        0.42429447  
7        0.323540698  
8        0.865984245  
9        0.856875894  
10       0.721728497  
11       0.634773162  
12       0.563059042  
13       0.545131335  
14       0.029808531  
15       0.645993399  
16       0.143720835  
17       0.949973296  
18       0.14425803  
19       0.414601876   
20       0.53421424  
21       0.826148814  
22       0.194818367  
23       0.942334356  
24       0.837107013  
25       0.291448263  
26       0.242588271  
27       0.939609775  
28       0.500159997  
29       0.428897293  
30       0.41946448
```